# Select a single element that occurs in two lists

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I need to find a single property by it's name out of a list of properties that matches a string from another list which is being generated based on the type of the declaring type.

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ Properties  ║      Names      ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ User.UserId ║ Id              ║
║ User.Name   ║ IdUser          ║
║ User.Age    ║ UserId <- MATCH ║
║ User.Email  ║ Key             ║
║             ║ UserKey         ║
║             ║ KeyUser         ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

---

```
private const string IdAffix = "Id";
private const string KeyAffix = "Key";

private static readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable<string>> GetIdentityNamePatterns
    = type => new [] { IdAffix, KeyAffix, type.Name + IdAffix, IdAffix + Type.Name,...}

private Expression<Func<TEntity, TIdentity> KeySelector = entity =>
{
    var type = typeof(TEntity);

    if(type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEntity<TIdentity>)))
        return ((IEntity<TIdentity>) entity).Id;

    const BindingFlags bindingFlags
        = BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public;

    var properties = type.GetProperties(bindingFlags);

    var identityProperty = entityProperties.SingleOrDefault(x =>
        Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(IdentityAttribute)) && x.PropertyType == typeof (TIdentity))
        // this is where I'm stuck
        // how to loopthe list of possible names while looping
        // through the properties at the same time?
        ?? entityProperties.SingleOrDefault(
            x => x.Name.Equals... // GetIdentityNamePatterns(type)
```

Comment: [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) may be useful to you

Comment: So - Basically you want to return the property of some object - where the name of that property exists in some other list? Is that all?

Comment: Looks like the OP wants to find `UserId` for example in the list on the right when selecting `User.UserId` from the Left I would look at the .Contains() Method or IndexOf(".") to get everything to the right of the `"."` that would return the Key Value to search on in the Right List [List<T>.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean -
Basically you want to return the property of some object - where the name of that property exists in some other list?

```
var namesToMatch = GetIdentityNamePatterns(type);

var property = entityProperties
    .FirstOrDefault(p => namesToMatch.Any(n => x => x.Name.Equals(n)));
```